# Pandas extract str in column with regex

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe, in one column I want to extract a specific information. Using split it can be done easily but with Pandas I cannot figure out how to do it.

```
s = pd.Series(['T:15.0(1.71%),B:7.4(0.03%),P:1e-21'])
```

I want to extract only 1e-21

I tried

```
s.str.extract()
```

But I cannot find the regex to match what I want actually.

Or if there is another way to parse column content.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this:

```
print(s.str.extract('(\d+e-\d+)'))

       0
0  1e-21
```

Answer (score 1):

```
s = pd.Series(['T:15.0(1.71%),B:7.4(0.03%),P:1e-21'])
print(s.str.split(":")[0][-1])
```

Output:

```
'1e-21'
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```py
print(s.str.extract(r"P:([^\,]+)"))
```

This will return whatever you have after literal: `P:` which isn't comma (since I understand comma terminates assignment).